# Resolving version conflict in maven java project when adding dependencies via parent

Tags: java, maven

For some reason I have to import dependencies from project "A" into my Java project "B" using parent. I don't have the ability to change this project "A". But my project "B" uses an newer version of the Spark library. After importing dependencies using parent, the class code of project "A" does not work correctly, as it picks up my version of Spark.
Can I force Maven to compile classes of project "A" with the version of the Spark library that is specified by it, and compile my classes with the version of the Spark library that is specified by me?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one should avoid that and try to find a version that fits for all purposes.

If this is not possible, one could try with Maven Shade Plugin.